# Windows XP always boots as administrator

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I am using Windows XP Professional. Whenever I boot my machine it always logs in as administrator. I understand that it's not good from the security point of view.

How can I make Windows log in as general user?

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog box.

Enter "**control userpasswords2**" and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

Tick the check box labeled "*Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer*"

Make sure you have a standard user account setup to log into (You'll still be able to log into the Administrator account after a restart, so don't stress if you don't have it setup already.) Do this via the control panel.

Answer (score 2):

After logging on , go to User Accounts and create a new user with User Level privileges and set a password for Administrator .

Answer (score 0):

One advantage to no passwords on accounts is:

"To protect users who do not password-protect their accounts, Windows XP Professional accounts without passwords can only be used to log on at the physical computer console. By default, accounts with blank passwords can no longer be used to log on to the computer remotely over the network, or for any other logon activity except at the main physical console logon screen."

[Source](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/windows_xp_your_definitive_lockdown_guide.html) found under "Set stronger password policies"

Best solution is to set up a regular user account, or a Limited User Account to use on a daily basis, password protect all accounts with strong passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Open `control panel --> user account` to create new user account.
When you start up your PC you can see all user accounts you created,choose one to start.